# Force git pull to resolve divergent by discard all local commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

## The question

I have a local repo with 3 commits:

```
A -> B -> C
```

And the remote repo has another 3 commits:

```
A -> B -> D
```

How to make `git pull` to resolve the divergent by discarding all local commits? The local repo after `git pull --some-magic` should be:

```
A -> B -> D
```

Note that, `git reset HEAD~1 --hard` won't work, because my script doesn't know how many commits must be reverted to avoid a conflict.

## Why I need this

I'm writing a script to sync between github and gitlab repositories. One of them is a read-only mirror. My scripts just try `git pull --force` from origin1 and `git push` to origin2.

However, if someone changed the history of `origin1`, the `git pull` in my script would fail with an error message. The only way to solve the problem is delete the whole local repository, and perform `git clone` from stretch. It's wasting bandwidth and slow!

Comment: what about looping/while the git pull command does not succeed, do ```git reset HEAD~1 --hard```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not do this with `git pull`, because `git pull` is designed for a different purpose: to *combine work*.  But you don't *want* to combine work; you want to *mirror their latest commit*.

To achieve that, simply run `git fetch` to obtain their latest commit, then use `git reset --hard` to reset your local branch to their latest commit.  The only tricky part is that `git reset --hard` demands the identity of their latest commit.  That's available to you: if you know that your local branch name is `main` because their branch name is `main`, your own Git will have updated your `origin/main`, so you can use `git reset --hard origin/main`.

Alternatively, you can use the *upstream* setting of the current branch:

```
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

Note that this will throw out both committed and uncommitted work, so be careful with it.